# Access Variable From another Class to Be Used In SQL Statement JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, global-variables

This is probably a easy question for you guys but I'm trying to access a variable set by an SQL statement to then be passed into another SQL statement in another class.

The idea is that when the user logs in, I get their StaffID then I want to use that number in another SELECT statement.

I've tried to make the variable public and access it from the other class but it returns empty.

LOGIN CODE:

```
public static String StaffID;


// SignIn ActionListener 
            signIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {

                    try{
                    Class.forName(DRIVER);
                    // Connection to the Database
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"root","");

                    // Gets text from textfields and assigns them to variables
                    s1 = tfUsername.getText();
                    s2 = tfPassword.getText();

                    Statement st = con.createStatement();   


                    // SQL Statements 
                    st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login WHERE UName= '"+s1+"' and PWord = '"+s2+"'");


                    // Extracts data from statement to a result set
                    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();


                    if (rs.next())
                    {
                    // Gets text from Textfields and assigns them to variables
                    StaffID = rs.getString("StaffID");

                    }
```

OTHER CLASS:

```
try{
                    Class.forName(DRIVER);
                    // Connection to the Database
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"root","");

                    signIn sign = new signIn();

                    //Creates Statement Connection
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();   

                    // SQL Statements 
                    st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM rota WHERE StaffID = '"+sign.StaffID+"'");

                    // Extracts data from statement to a result set
                    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();

                    if (rs.next()) {

                        tfRotaTask1.setText(rs.getString("Task1"));
                        tfRotaTask2.setText(rs.getString("Task2"));
                        tfRotaTask3.setText(rs.getString("Task3"));
                        tfRotaTask4.setText(rs.getString("Task4"));
                        tfRotaTask5.setText(rs.getString("Task5"));
                        tfRotaTask6.setText(rs.getString("Task6"));
                        tfRotaTask7.setText(rs.getString("Task7"));
                        tfRotaTask8.setText(rs.getString("Task8"));


                        }
                    else{
                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Staff Member Not Found");
                    }
```

To put this into context, I'm making a staff managment rota system.

Sorry if my Java seems poor :(

Any help will do.

Comment: Use [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Your SQL is subject to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Ok first thing first, wrap your Queries in One Class for more easy use.

```
    public class QueryUtils
    {
     public static String staffId(...yourArgs)
    {
    String staffId = "";
     // Make the logic for getting the StringId
    return staffId;
    }
}
```

Ok so you can call this query from anywhere in your application. Even from other queries. Use basic **OOP and Patter Desings** and you will solve this issues.

Comment: So you're saying to to make new class and write the SQL statement that will return the StaffID? What do i put in the ''yourArgs' bit? :)

Comment: Well the args you need for making that function as you can see you need two args for that query. UserName and a PAssword so two Strings.

Answer (score 0):

you don't inti the value of the StaffID until the condition of     rs.next() is be true
try to make else statement like this

```
 if (rs.next())
                {
                // Gets text from Textfields and assigns them to variables
                StaffID = rs.getString("StaffID");

                }
```

and then test the value of the StaffID in the other class if it null then you have somthing wrong in the executeQuery
because i don't see any thing wrong in your code